# I want to use locale data fr-FR in Filemaker using fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar, filemaker

I am using fullCalendar in a Filemaker DB, and I have learned how to use my own data for the calendar, and how to build scripts to add events.

Now I would like to change something in the calendar layout. For example, I want to use locale data `fr`.

I don't know where to go to change settings for calendar, I don't know where to change settings I have seen on calendar documentation.

Attached a layout where can find any settings, but I cannot find "locale" for example, to change international setting.

Hope I have explained right, thanks.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it would be in the very bottom box in your screenshot (the JSFunction one)...in the `$("#calendar").fullCalendar({...` bit you'd set the locale option along with the other calendar settings (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/locale for details and an example). You also need to add another JS file containing the locale data (again see the documentation page for details).

Comment: P.S. Even if you're stuck with fullCalendar 3 (not the latest version by a long way), you'd be advised to update it from 3.01 to the latest patch in that branch (3.10 I think, from memory) so you get bug fixes etc - quite a lot was fixed during version 3's lifetime. You can get the source code from a CDN and paste it into your filemaker config.

Comment: I added the $("#calendar").fullCalendar({ locale:"fr"  but nothing changer i have this project demo contains calendar in filemaker in English and want to convert on french if you have the steps can you please share with me thanks

Comment: did you add `locale:"fr" ` within the existing `$("#calendar").fullCalendar({` which is there in the file already? You mustn't add a second `$("#calendar").fullCalendar({` to the list. Also, you need to add the relevant locale data file as I mentioned above...did you do that?

Comment: I added just locale:"fr" in $("#calendar").fullCalendar({ , locale data file? how can i find this file and when i can add in filemaker so if you have the steps can you help me

Comment: The documentation https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/locale describes where to obtain the file - I mentioned this in my first comment. As for putting it in filemaker, I don't that platform but I can see from your screenshot you already have extra files added via the "JS1" and "JS2" boxes, so maybe you can add a "JS3" box and paste the locale file in there?

Comment: I don't know how can i add that so not clear thanks for you

Comment: Perhaps you can just paste it at the bottom of the existing JS1 box (after the main fullCalendar code) and it would be ok as well, i don't know